# Get access to child items in MenuItem when ItemsSource is use, C#\WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, itemssource

I have MenuItem that uses ItemsSource.

```
<MenuItem Name="Profiles" Header="Profiles list" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="12" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding _profiles, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}">
```

When I try to access an item I get an item from ItemsSource...
How can I get access in codebehind to MenuItems in foreach like below?

```
foreach (MenuItem mi in Profiles.Items)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get access to individual menuitems using **parent menuitem's click event** in this case:

```
    Profiles.Click += profileClick;
    private void profileClick (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
         MenuItem item = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
         //you can use item.Name and item.Header to identify the MenuItem
    }
```

then you can use the item variable for your purpose :)